# Github - search merges

Tags: git, search, merge

Is it possible to search through merge conflicts only in github?

I was doing a merge a few days ago. I remember merging something with something else, and now i'm getting an error that seems related to that merge.

Only issue is I can't remember for the life of me where I made that merge. I have the error code so I figure if I can search the merge conflicts for that error I might come up with something.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Clone the repository
2. `git bisect`
3. ??
4. Profit

`git bisect` helps you to find exactly which commit introduced a bug. As far as I'm aware there is no direct Github interface for this.